# Paragraph character count

Tags: java

I have a txt file where there are multiple paragraphs and they are delimited by a "%". I'm trying to find the maximum characters for every line in every separate paragraphs in order to make a padding. My problem is that it finds the maximum number of character overall, instead of finding the max in every paragraph/

```
int nmar = 0;
int max = 0;

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    input.useDelimiter("%");
    String nume = input.next();
    lines = linii;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(nume);

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String linecount = scan.nextLine();
        nmar = linecount.length();

        if (nmar > max) {
            max = nmar;
        } else if (nmar == 0) {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println(max);
    }
}
```

Comment: Should `input.useDelimiter("%");` come before your call to `input.hasNextLine()`?

Comment: Why should it? It's just checking if there's another line. Is it not sufficient that it comes before `next()`?

Comment: Can you share a simple example of input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I moved the `nmar` and `max` inside the while to reset them at every paragraph, seems to work.

```
int nmar, max;

while (input.hasNextLine()) {
    nmar = 0;
    max = 0;
    input.useDelimiter("%");
    String nume = input.next();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(nume);

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String linecount = scan.nextLine();
        nmar = linecount.length();

        if (nmar > max) {
            max = nmar;
        } else if (nmar == 0) {
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println(max);
}
```

With this input

```
dkdjdhd\ndpepe%nd\njkfdlfrkefjrekl%dffd
```

I get

```
7
15
4
```